# Does anyone know a good resource that gives a full tutorial on UV unwrapping?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm currently amateur-ok at UV unwrapping, but I want to learn how I can straighten UV islands and be able to organize them better, but I haven't found any good resources.

Does anyone know a good one?

Comment: Here are some helpful UV Unwrapping tutorials from Blender Guru: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBUfMKKZDo | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k